# SPRINGMVCのパスについて

Tags: java, spring, java8

今独自でSPRINGMVCのシステムを作っています。サーバーは起動するのですが、パスを打つと画面が表示されません。すみませんがご回答よろしくお願いいたします。
Eclipse4.6
STS3.8
Tomcat8
Spring4.3.2

WEB.XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
 version="3.1">
 <filter>
  <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>encoding</param-name>
   <param-value>utf-8</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
   <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
   <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
   <page-encoding>utf-8</page-encoding>
   <scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>
   <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp</include-prelude>
  </jsp-property-group>
 </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

JSPの場所
webapp/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp

パスは色々試していました
localhost:18080/SpringMVC
localhost:18080/SpringMVC/index.jsp

Comment: コードをハイライトすると質問がより見やすくなるかと思います。コードハイライトはマークダウン形式で記載してください。また、コードを選択し`｛｝`を押すことでコードを自動でマークダウンできます。

Answer (score 2):

WEB-INF配下のファイルはクライアント(ブラウザ)から直接見ることはできません。

JSPファイルを直接表示(コントローラを作らずに)させたいのであれば、WEB-INFの外に置く必要があります。

`webapp/index.jsp`に配置すれば質問に書かれているパスで表示できるようになります。